# How to configure Eclipse to debug with docker and gdb?

Tags: eclipse, docker, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging

With following setup:

- ubuntu VM, running eclipse C/C++ IDE
- ubuntu 16.04 docker container with PTXdist build system and gcc toolchain
- source code in VM filesystem mounted to docker container
- remote target connected via SSH

What works and what not:

- PTXdist: build project from command line - OK, works
- make: build project from command line - OK, works
- gdb: from command line - attach to binary in running container works
- eclipse:

  - debug configuration calls python script which executes docker gdb in running container
  - FAILED with timeout on gdb version

It looks like the gdb machine interface is not reachable from eclipse while checking the gdb version (as a connection test?).
Already tried to attach STDIN,STDOUT to the container, but without success.

Does anyone have a hint to configure this setup?

P.S. The next step will be to switch from ubuntu VM to Windows 10 (with Docker Desktop + WSL2)